# Executing an existing DocumentDB stored procedure in JAVA

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

I have an existing stored procedure and want to execute it inside a java program. Is there any example which shows how to do this without creating the stored procedure in the same program?

My stored procedure has two input parameters:

```
function Get_last_sync_time(name, phone_no) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Stored procedures in DocumentDB are *durable*, just like any other data you store. They are not scoped to a running program. Maybe edit your question to be more specific? Right now it really doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

In order to execute a stored procedure you need to first create it inside the DocumentDB database using [createStoredProcedure API](http://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-java/com/microsoft/azure/documentdb/DocumentClient.html#createStoredProcedure-java.lang.String-com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.StoredProcedure-com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.RequestOptions-). I'm not sure if by "existing" stored procedure you mean that it's already inside DocumentDB or not. If it is, you can use [executeStoredProcedure API](http://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-java/com/microsoft/azure/documentdb/DocumentClient.html#executeStoredProcedure-java.lang.String-com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.RequestOptions-java.lang.Object:A-) to execute it.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-java/blob/master/test/com/microsoft/azure/documentdb/GatewayTests.java#L1583) to create and execute a stored procedure in DocumentDB.

Let me know if that resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a reference to the existing stored procedure using

```
StoredProcedure sProc = docDbClient.queryStoredProcedures(docDBCollection.getSelfLink(), new SqlQuerySpec("SELECT * FROM root r where r.id='" + "Get_last_sync_time" + "'"), null).getQueryIterable().toList().get(0);
```

Once you have the reference, call the stored procedure

```
StoredProcedureResponse res = docDbClient.executeStoredProcedure(sProc.getSelfLink(), options, new Object[]{params});
```

The options object is of type `RequestOptions` and can be used to set properties like the partition key if you are using a partitioned DocumentDB